# jQuery Custom Label Validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate

I'm wanting to manipulate the positioning of the jQuery Validate plugin label positioning on submission.

When you view the form, press submit and you will notice the labels I have are being replaced by the validation plugin. This is ok but I'm not wanting a double up in labels.

I'm wanting the error message to replace the existing label text so that one label handles what the input is used for and the error message. I'm unsure if this is possible.

Here are my current validation rules:

```
validation: function () {
        $('form').validate({
            rules: {
                "email": {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                },
                    "name": {
                    required: true
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Here is a working example of what I have: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/89y26/115/)

Comment: The jQuery Validate plugin creates and toggles its own error labels.  That being said, by the wording of your question, I'm having a hard time determining if there is something wrong with the operation of your jsFiddle or if you just want to remove any potential redundancy in your code.  So what part, if any, of your jsFiddle is not working properly?

Answer (score 1):

I've just adjusted your [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/89y26/117/) adding the CSS

```
fieldset label:nth-of-type(even)
{
 display:none;
}
```

When you click submit, the second label isn't displayed.

**Update** for the question in the comment: I've made another CSS adjustment for this, [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bbo8164g/):

```
fieldset label[style*='display: none'] + label
{
  display:block;
  color:#007c92;
  top:15px;
  position:absolute;
  left:23px;
  font-size:0.7em;
  font-weight:bold;
 }
```

I'm not sure if that's what you would like to have - name as well as email now keeps displaying the label on top of correct entries. This could be adjusted in case this should only be done for the email.
Without those CSS adjustments, it looks like the validate plugin would only initially display the label in the input, display an error message in the label in case of error and sets the label to `display:none` in case of correct entries. Possibly there's an option / setting in the validate plugin to have this functionality without using this kind of workaround, but maybe you already checked for that.

Comment: I feared that may have been the solution. Thanks heaps for this. Would you have a work around for the Email label? When you enter a correct email the label disappears for the input?

Comment: @Filth Glad if I was able to help you, and just updated my answer for the second issue.

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure if this is what you're seeking, however, you do not need to hide your original labels when you display the jQuery Validate labels.  You could simply replace the text of your default label with the error message text in a single line within the `errorPlacement` callback function...

```
errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
    $(element).next('label').text(error.text());
}
```

**Proof of concept:  http://jsfiddle.net/z2gpjf03/**

---

Obviously, it needs a little more work, but it shows how much of your code could be eliminated all while utilizing one set of labels as you requested.

http://jsfiddle.net/89y26/178/

Comment: Hey man thanks so much for this - Your answer sparked a bit of research and I fixed my solution. Here is the solution! http://jsfiddle.net/89y26/236/

Comment: @Filth, I'm glad to help.  However, looking at your demo, I can say that you **absolutely should not** be doing anything with classes from within the `errorPlacement` function.  It's only meant for placing the error within the layout.

Answer (score 0):

Right guys I've done it! Was a mission but so glad to have this working: http://jsfiddle.net/89y26/236/

Basically it's using the `highlight` and `unhighlight` functions to check if each input is valid to then append valid or error classes and style appropriately.

Ignore the icon styling but feel free to use this guys and manipulate how you like!

```
validation: function() {
        $('form').validate({
            rules: {
                "name": {
                    required: true
                },
                "email": {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                }
            },
            //Add Error Class To Fieldset if field invalid
            highlight: function(element) {
                $(element).parent().removeClass('form--valid').addClass('form--error');
                $(element).next('.input-label').hide();
            },
            //Add Valid Class To Fieldset if field valid
            unhighlight: function(element) {
                $(element).parent().removeClass('form--error').addClass('form--valid');
                $(element).next('.error').hide();
                $(element).parent('fieldset').find('.input-label').show();
            },
            errorPlacement: function(error, element){
                error.addClass('input-label--error').insertBefore(element);
                //Add Error class to fieldset
                element.parent('fieldset').addClass('form--error');
            }
      });
   }
```

Comment: I cannot endorse this solution in its present form.  Also , please put the relevant code within the answer to make it independent from the jsFiddle.  Thanks.

Comment: You **absolutely should not** be doing anything with styles or classes from within the `errorPlacement` function.  It's only meant for placing the error within the layout

Comment: I understand Sparky but I guess requirements are requirements and I couldn't find another suitable solution. I will edit my answer with appropriate code.